# How to reduce the difference between training and validation in the loss curve?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, time-series, transformer-model, overfitting-underfitting

I have used the Transformer model to train the time series dataset, but there is always a gap between training and validation in my loss curve. I have tried using different learning rates, batch sizes, dropout, heads, dim_feedforward, and layers, but they don't work. Can anyone give me some ideas on reducing the gap between them?

[image]

I also tried to ask the question on the Pytorch forum but didn't get any reply.
[How to design a decoder for time series regression in Transformer?](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-design-a-decoder-for-time-series-regression-in-transformer/162000)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are overfitting your model here
1.Try using more data.
2.Try to add dropOut layers
3. Try using lasso or Ridge